# Remove 'bouncy scrolling' on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I'm trying to find a way to get rid of the bouncy scrolling behaviour on mobile devices (e.g. when there is no content below to scroll yet you are still able to do it and scroll content to top and when released it bounces back)

My html structure looks like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="container">
```

where all elements stretch to full height of the window. I tried overflow hidden on html and body, auto etc.. yet nothing seems to achieve a state where if you scroll than it doesn't scroll unless there is more content below.

Comment: Can you add more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is to disable the scroll bounce for a UIWebView in iOS. If you're developing a native iOS app, you can disable the bounce by setting `[WebViewObject].bounces = NO` where [WebViewObject] is the UIWebView.

If you're just looking to prevent the bounce in the Safari mobile browser, I don't believe there's a way to do this.